# NginX http redirection to https returns unreadable respone

Tags: http, redirect, nginx, https

I want to redirect all http requests to https with NginX, but I have some difficulties with it.

Here is my vhost file :

```
server {
    gzip off;
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name mydomain.fr www.mydomain.fr sub.otherdom.fr otherdom.fr;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html index.htm;
    ssl on;
    server_name mydomain.fr www.mydomain.fr sub.otherdom.fr otherdom.fr;
    ssl_certificate /root/tmp/live-ecdsa/mydomain.fr/0001_chain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /root/tmp/live-ecdsa/mydomain.fr/privkey-p384.pem;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/default.access.log;
    charset utf-8;
    location  / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }
        }
```

Trying to access these domain over plain http with different browsers results in the following :
Chrome/Firefox : downloading a file filled with bytes data

Edge : displays a blank page with `€ÿÿÿÿ`

A `curl -I mydomain.fr` outputs `▒▒`

Accessing these domains directly over https works.
I have already tried with both `return 301 https://$host$request_uri;` and `return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, although user6788523 response helped me with the debugging, the fault was on my side.

I had several other vhost files with the http2 directive associated with the http port 80 (`listen [::]:80 http2;`). Removing the `http2` directive resolved the problem.

This setting must be used only with ssl enabled server block

Answer (score 2):

I suspect it has something to do with the fairly large number of server names you are declaring in the one server name field inside a pretty locally scoped context. Although, if I'm honest thats a fairly unfounded assertion based on habits I've become user to.

I'd suggest a few things, although generally most of this wont fix your problem, it might make it easier to work out whats happening:

- split your config into purposed files. Ie. Create a ssl.conf in another folder which contains all youe cert settings, cipher suites etc. Then add an include /path/to/ssl.conf in your config.
- dont use $host, this variable can be set by the use so probably a less than great idea

Assuming you have all the other relevant ssl/tls settings referenced from somewhere else then the below should roughly work.

```
server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  listen [::]:80 default_server;
  server_name mydomain.fr;
  return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
  listen 443 ssl http2 default_server;
  listen [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server;
  root /usr/share/nginx/html;
  $server_name mydomain.fr
  location  / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
  }
}
```